# Round numbers to the closest number with all digits equal to zero but the first digit

Tags: r

I would round numbers to make all digits zero except one. So for instance, if I have `2341` I would round down to `2000` and up to `3000`, for `324` I would round down to `300` and up to `400`. Is there a way to round numbers so all digits are zero except the first one? 
Ideally this should also work with small numbers, so `0.0568` would be rounded down to `0.05` and up to `0.06`.

Function like `roundUp <- function(x) 10^ceiling(log10(x))` would round up to the closest power of 10  [or lower power if changing `ceiling` for `floor`) but in this case `324` would be rounded up to `1000` whereas I would round it up to `400` and down to `300`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Michael Lugo answer but making it capable of dealing with negative numbers (like @Stefan Zechner answer) and also adding up and down rounding I did the following.

```
round_to_zeros = function(x, num.sig.figs = 1, round.down = TRUE){
  initial.x <- as.numeric(x)
  if(x == 0){return(0)}
  if(x < 0){x <- (-1*x)}
  power_of_ten = floor(log(x, 10))

  number_down <- round(floor(x/10^power_of_ten), num.sig.figs-1)*10^power_of_ten
  number_up   <- round( x /10^power_of_ten, num.sig.figs-1)*10^power_of_ten

  if(initial.x < 0){
    if(round.down==TRUE){return(-1*number_up)} else {return(-1*number_down)} }

  if(round.down==TRUE){return(number_down)} else {return(number_up)}
}
```

This rounds up and down and deals with both negative and positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

i think the following function does what you want, worked for all examples, also negative values:

```
special_round <- function(x, type)
{
  z = floor(log10(abs(x)))
  y = 10^z
  res = x/y
  if(type == "up" )
  { 
    res <- ceiling(res)
  }
  if(type == "down")
  {    
    res <- floor(res)
  }
  return(res*y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will round `x` to `num.sig.figs` significant figures.  (You want to round to 1 significant figure.)

```
round_sigfigs = function(x, num.sig.figs = 1){
  power_of_ten = floor(log(x, 10))
  return(round(x/10^power_of_ten, num.sig.figs-1)*10^power_of_ten)
}
```

For example: `round_sigfigs(2341, 1)` is `2000` and `round_sigfigs(0.0568, 1)` is `0.06`, as asked for.  `round_sigfigs(2341, 2)` is `2300`, rounding to two places.

The built-in R function  `signif` handles this automatically.

Comment: I have added an answer extending yours. If you disagree please let me know.