# Round number up to next value where all digits are zero except the first

Tags: python, rounding

I would like to round a number up to the next value where all digits are zero except the first.

- `123` --> `200`
- `8472` --> `9000`
- etc.

> Note: This same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674550/round-numbers-to-the-closest-number-with-all-digits-equal-to-zero-but-the-first), but want the answer for Python, not R.

Answer (score 0):

I modified some of these ideas from [RealPython](https://realpython.com/python-rounding/#rounding-up) to do this kind of rounding.

```py
import numpy as np
def round_up_to_zeros(n):
    multiplier = 10 ** (-int(np.log10(n)))
    return np.ceil(n * multiplier) / multiplier
```

```py
round_up_to_zeros(123)
OUT: 200.0

round_up_to_zeros(8472)
OUT: 9000.0
```

However, this is only works for positive numbers.